# How can I find this constant?

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

My friend asked this question in our class:
 let X be a random variable which has a cumulative distribution function

[image].

Find (a).

I think (a) cannot be solved but my other friend thinks (a) = 5/8 without any solution. Please help me to find this value. Thank you.

Comment: this should be tagged `self-study` ... though regular answerers (hint hint) should have figured out that you identified it as one in your question and treated it according to our [guidelines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CDF must be right continuous, non-decreasing, and have limit $0$ as $x\to-\infty$ and limit $1$ as $x\to\infty$. So any value of $a$ greater than or equal to $\frac14$ and less than or equal to $1$ will make your $F$ a valid CDF.

Comment: Sorry, I tag this post as pmf and cdf but it always changes to pdf. So, if this is a cdf of pmf, does (a) still be greater than 1/4 and less than or equal to 1?

Comment: @16POP Yes, the CDF requirements are the same for both pmf and pdf.